# Installing a 64-bit on a 32-bit dell inspiron 1720, ramifications?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation

I have a dell inspiron 1720, which isn't a 32-bit system.

I already have a 64-bit cd burned from MSDN.

I just want to know what the ramifications are of installing a 64-bit on this laptop?
Will it run slower since it should really have a 32-bit version on it?

Answer (score 1):

looking at the specs here: http://www.dell.com/us/en/gen/notebooks/inspnnb_172x/pd.aspx?refid=inspnnb_172x&s=gen

all processors available in the 1720 should support a 64bit OS fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little muddled by grammar mistakes but if I'm reading your question right. A 64-bit OS won't install on a 32-bit processor at all.

Well, I take that back. A poorly written installer may let you install the OS but you wouldn't be able to run it. The Windows 7 install and all Linux distros I've ever used properly detect the processor during the install and won't let you install a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit processor.

[warrenkopp](https://superuser.com/users/9495/warrenkopp) is correct, by the way. Every supported processor for the Inspiron 1720 is a 64-bit processor. You'd be hard-pressed to find a system manufactured in the past 3 years that ships with a 32-bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed with confidence. I reload all my Dells from scratch with x64 operating systems. As a rule this will work on all systems as long as the CPU supports 64 bit. The only issues you may run across is with drivers for device support. Before you begin your transformation record all the devices found in your hardware device manager. After loading your 64bit OS go back into the hardware device manager to check that everything is recognized correctly - it should be unless you are using an older laptop with legacy hardware.

As a general rule, all the major brand laptops that are Centrino branded or are core iX branded will be supported for Windows or Linux x64 operating systems.